# Can I get a diagramming tool with a transparent background, for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, diagrams

I would like to be able to a diagramming tool's main window over another application's window, so that I can trace areas from the base window with drawing elements on the overlaid window. I can take a screenshot of the base window and use it in the bottom layer of a diagram, but that brings the risk of building diagrams off an out of date base image, and I could even automate the update of the base image when I start the diagramming tool. Both of these seem a bit of a kludge compared to synchronising resizes and moves on both windows and one with a transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44915/how-to-change-window-transparency-in-windows-7/) to set the window translucency (from completely transparent to opaque) of `any` diagramming tool. That way, you can set the diagramming tool window to 5% transparency, which will let you see the window behind the diagramming tool and trace anything off of it.

Comment: +1 for nudging me over to AutoHotKey. I've been building up to looking or something like that for a while. Now I just need to find a diagramming tool with tool windows that can float outside of the main window, like The Gimp, but with vectors.

Comment: Try: http://inkscape.org/